# how to draw a rectangle around the logo?

Tags: python, opencv

I have a litte problem.
[source image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDAaK.png)
There is a logo which i must to detect and make rectangle around it.

I wrote some code:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('9.png')
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (3, 3), 0)
_, binary = cv2.threshold(blur, 100, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C)

plt.imshow(binary, cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

And got this result: [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGgx6.png)
And now i dont know how to draw a rectangle around it

Comment: welcome. [tour], [ask], [mre]. break your task down. research individual steps. (1) object detection (2) drawing a rectangle. -- your approach doesn't detect the logo.

Comment: Try to display `binary` with `cv2.imshow`. Please explain, what you mean by "detect"? Do you want to find the logo in another image amongst other objects?

Comment: Why is your result in color when you convert to gray and then threshold to binary?  Your pyplot is using a gray colormap also. So there is no reason for a color result.  I suggest using cv2.imshow() rather than plt.imshow(). Why are you using adaptive threshold. You just need to threshold so that the background is separated from the rest with a simple threshold or cv2.inRange().  Be sure your logo becomes white and the rest black.  Then get the biggest  external contour. Then get its bounding box.

Answer (score 0):

here is how:

```
img = cv2.imread('img.png')

temp = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, temp = cv2.threshold(temp, thresh=0, maxval=255, type=cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)
temp = cv2.dilate(temp, kernel, iterations=1)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(temp, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contours[0])

# draw a rectangle around the image
cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 1)
```